# mongoose populate naming and structure

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, populate

I have this "User" model where I store friends, this friends have some option

```
// Prepare schema
var schema = new db.Schema({
    friends: [{
        active : Boolean,
        user : { type: db.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'user' },
        options : [{ type: db.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'friend_option' }],
    }],
    image: { type: db.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'file' },
    password: { 
        type: String, 
        select: false
    },
    email: String,
    name: String,
    udid: [{
        device: String,
        udid: String
    }],
    created_on: Date
});
```

here I get one user with his friends

```
var friendQuery = User.find( {_id:req.params.id});
friendQuery.select('friends');
friendQuery.populate({ path: 'friends._id', model: 'user', select:'_id name' });        
friendQuery.exec(
    function(err, user) {
    if (err)
        res.send(err);
        res.send(user);
});
```

my question is, why the result have a different name from my model? why friends->_id->_id instead go friends->user->_id?

```
friends": [
      {
        "_id": {
          "_id": "58025664c154929d3207b232",
          "name": "User 1"
        },
        "options": [
        ],
        "active": false
      },
      {
        "_id": {
          "_id": "580257e1e3cd4fc7326fa97b",
          "name": "User 2"
        },
        "options": [
        ],
        "active": false
      }
    ]
```

another option, this solution is good for an hypothetical big app?

Answer (score 0):

The way You are using this in incorrect just make a simple change in your query

```
 var friendQuery = User.find( {_id:req.params.id});
friendQuery.select('friends');
friendQuery.populate({ path: 'friends.user', model: 'user', select:'_id name' });        
friendQuery.exec(
    function(err, user) {
    if (err)
        res.send(err);
        res.send(user);
});
```

as you are taking reference of your user in friends array simply replace _id from query to user that will definitely work for you